# Stable way to use integrated graphics with dedicated graphics on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nouveau

Recently I dug up the Internet on an attempt to use the integrated GPU to display and the dedicated GPU (GeForce 940M) running on `nouveau` to work together. I've tried both `nouveau` and `nvidia-375` but none worked (believe or not, `nouveau` gives better FPS). For `nouveau` I used `optirun glxgears` but this happened:

```
diamond@K401LB:~$ optirun glxgears
[ 3483.103063] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE)     Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 3483.103097] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

For the proprietary driver, I used `bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia` and `primusrun`. However, the system just straight up froze. Also I don't know if it's related or not, but my HDMI port died afterward.

P/S: with `nouveau`, games like Team Fortress 2 are crashing.

P/P/S: with `nouveau`, seems like all 3D apps are crashing. Logs for Minecraft: https://pastebin.com/aMQFr2cW (I'm going back to nvidia-375)